# Calculate the expected bonus payment from the insurer to the 1000 policyholders in one year.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value

An auto insurance company is implementing a new bonus system. In each month, if a policyholder does not have an accident, he or she will receive a 5.00 cash-back bonus from the insurer. Among the 1000 policyholders, 400 are classified as low-risk drivers and 600 are classified as high-risk drivers. In each month, the probability of zero accidents for high-risk drivers is 0.8 and that for low-risk drivers is 0.9.

Calculate the expected bonus payment from the insurer to the 1000 policyholders in one year.

**My attempt**

Let $X=\text{high-risk drivers}, Y=\text{low-risk drivers}, D=\text{accident-free driver in one month}$

$D=(X \cap D) \cup (Y \cap D)$

$P(D)=P(X \cap D)+P(Y \cap D)=P(X)P(D|X)+P(Y)P(D|Y)=(600/1000)(80/100)+(400/1000)(90/100)=0.84$.

So the probability that a randomly selected policyholder experiences zero accidents in a month is $0.84$.

Thus the expected # of accident-free drivers in one month is $1000 \cdot 0.84=840$. That means $840$ people are expected to receive $5.00$ cash-back bonuses and so the bonus payment for the month amounts to $5 \cdot 840=4200$.

$\therefore$ the expected bonus payment in one year is $12 \cdot 4200=50,400$.

Alternative solution:

Let $X=\text{# of accidents for a high-risk driver each month}$,

$Y=\text{# of accidents for a low-risk driver each month}$, and $B_i=\text{bonus payment in month $i$}$ for $i \in \{1,2,...,12\}$ whereby

$B_i=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       600 \cdot 5, &  \hspace{2mm} X=0 \\
        400 \cdot 5, & \hspace{2mm} Y=0\\
 0, & \hspace{2mm} otherwise\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

$X=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       0.8, &  \hspace{2mm} x=0 \\
        0.2, & \hspace{2mm} x \ge 1\\
     \end{array}
   \right. , $$Y=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       0.9, &  \hspace{2mm} y=0 \\
        0.1, & \hspace{2mm} y \ge 1\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

$\mathbb{E}(B_1+B_2+...+B_{12})=12\mathbb{E}(B_1)=12[600\cdot 5P(X=0)+400 \cdot 5P(Y=0)]=(12)(3000)(0.8)+12(2000)(0.9)=50,400$

Comment: I think it's your definition of $X$ which is confused. When you say "Let X =..." it seems to be the total number of accidents for all of the high risk drivers. But a couple of lines later you seem to be trying to define it as something to do with only one high risk driver. The first is a Binomial distribution, the second is Bernoulli (which sum up to a Binomial). Pick one definition for X (and Y) and stick to it and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I edited the post based on your feedback. Because the problem asks for the expected bonus payment to the $1000$ policyholders, we only consider the two cases where $X=0$ and $Y=0$ since this would encompass all the policyholders?